# data lost when I import mutile csv file to mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, pymysql

i have so many csv to import to mysql, so i try to use python/pandas/pymysql to import them into mysql
here r my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import datetime


if __name__ == '__main__':

    MYSQL_USER = 'root'
    MYSQL_PASSWORD = 'password'
    MYSQL_HOST_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    MYSQL_PORT = '3306'
    MYSQL_DATABASE = 'stocks'
    engine = create_engine(
        'mysql+pymysql://'
        + MYSQL_USER
        + ':'
        + MYSQL_PASSWORD
        + '@'
        + MYSQL_HOST_IP
        + ':'
        + MYSQL_PORT
        + '/'
        + MYSQL_DATABASE,
        echo=False
    )
    file_list = os.listdir('file')
    file_list_com = ['file/' + i for i in file_list]

    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    for i in file_list_com:
        print(i)
        df = pd.read_csv(i, encoding='ansi')
        df.iloc[:, :5].to_sql(
            'up_down_1',
            con=engine,
            if_exists='append',
            index=False,
            chunksize=500)
        print(i)
    print("**********************************")

    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(end - start)
```

it works perfect in terms of import data

but i try it for many times into some tables, 
and every time i  find that the row in the table is different, all rows may be 10,000,000, and every time it may lost 1000 rows or so.

could anyone tell me what happens?
and how can i solve the problem?
thanks a lot!!!

Comment: maybe the problem is not the insert , ...maybe the read_csv ....have you a log or a way for print the count pd.read_csv before the to_sql ??